# Can't access Redux Toolkit Query Error Property

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

Good day Devs.

I am pretty new on Redux toolkit query and I can't figure out what I am missing... Its been 2 days I have been on this.

My Challenge: I deliberately returned an error from my server and was hoping that RTK Query will handle the error property as explained [here](https://async-transformresponse--rtk-query-docs.netlify.app/concepts/error-handling/#errors-with-a-custom-basequery) but RTKQ keeps seeing it as isSuccess

Below is my slice code snippet

```
export const giftcards = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
endpoints: builder => ({
    getGiftcards: builder.query({
        query: () => ({ url: `/giftcards`, method: 'get', headers: getHeaders(), }),
        transformResponse: resp => giftcardsAdapter.setAll(initialState, resp?.data )
    }),
    getRates: builder.query({
        query: ( params ) => ({
            // Note I deliberately omitted the params; in other for the server to return an error message
            url: '/giftcard_rates', method: 'get', headers: getHeaders()
        })
    }),
}),
overrideExisting: true,
```

})

Below is my RTKQ hook found in my component.

```
const { isLoading, isSuccess, data : rates, error, isError } = useGetRatesQuery({ id,cid})
```

I expect to get **isError** to be true, and **error** should contain the error message.
However, RTQ is seeing the error as isSuccess;
below is the log message:

```
console.log({isError,error,isSuccess,isError,rates})

{
"error": undefined,
"isError": false,
"isSuccess": true,
"rates": Object {
    "error": Object {
        "data": Object {
            "message": "Country Id and Giftcard Id can not be empty.",
        },
        "status": 434,
    },
},
```

}

[My code for the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8GRG.png)

I believe the server is returning a valid error object, but why is RTK Query not seeing it as error.?

Thank you in advance!!!